# How stable and reliable is HAMMER in 2015?

Tags: filesystems, zfs, dragonfly-bsd, hammer

It's been a long time since HAMMER came about.

Has it been deemed reliable for general-purpose consumption yet?

Comment: That depends. What is it you're referring to?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, is it comparable to zfs in feature set and reliability?  E.g., if I'm not scared of DragonFly BSD itself, would DragonFly be a good choice if I want something like zfs?

Comment: Does that mean that HAMMER is a filesystem? You ought to have noticed that we have apparently never had a question about either it or DragonFly BSD. Thus it's probably not reasonable to assume that most people here know what they are...or anyone.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know of DFBSD and HAMMER (and deem it quite interesting piece of technology) and would probably assume others have at least heard as well ... Unfortunatelly never run it in production myself, so I'm sorry OP, can't help.

Comment: @Fox And I've heard of DragonFly BSD, but I had no idea that it was still an active project, let alone that anyone was using it for anything.

Comment: How to ask a better question: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault

Comment: @MichaelHampton, [BSD is Dying](http://www.google.com/search?q=bsd+is+dying), huh?

Comment: Possibly confusable with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat-assisted_magnetic_recording . BSD may not be dead yet but most folk use one of the big 3. Dragonfly is still a bit uncommon, and probably somewhat obscure.

Comment: When I say HAMMER, I mean, well, HAMMER.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAMMER

Answer (score 2):

I think *[MC Hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MC_Hammer)* is more financially stable now...

[image]

But if you're referring to [HAMMER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAMMER) the [filesystem](http://www.dragonflybsd.org/hammer/), um... nobody uses it or speaks of it... So low mindshare probably means it's not really gaining traction anywhere that counts.

Stick with [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) for your next-generation filesystem needs.

Comment: But that's the thing — I wasn't referring to *MC Hammer*, I was referring to *HAMMER*.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAMMER.